# How To Implement Search Option To DataGridView?

Tags: c#

Lasttime my question may not be clear.So I comeback with same clarification to get the answer.

I develop one small Windows Application.

In C# coding time while I press Ctrl+F then I can able to see Find Window.

Similarly I want to have a serch to my DataGridView, and its DataSource is MyTable1. When the user presses Ctrl+F then I would like to do search and locate on Particular Row-Column in DGV's DataSource column.

Is it possible? Or any other way?

Thanks For Ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2009/08/27/wpf-datagrid-search-and-highlight.aspx) with a simple sample of DataGrid search and highlight.

Answer (score 1):

the data table has a defualtview property, you can use the filter property to apply the search. its like sql but only with the part that comes after the where